ROS2 Communication Issues: Talker on Raspberry Pi Not Sending to WSL Listener via Multicast
I am having trouble with ROS2 communication between my raspberry pi container and WSL 2. I am running talker and listener demo nodes. The raspberry pi can hear the messages sent out by talker on WSl 2, but when the roles are reversed the WSL 2 does not hear the messages being published by the pi container.
The pi container and the WSL 2 are running ubuntu and have ros2 iron installed.
I disabled UFW on pi. I allowed UDP on ports 7400-8000 on my windows firewall and allowed edge traversal.
I checked what ports were being used by incoming data from pi using wireshark on my windows desktop (that is running WSL 2).
I then manually subscribed WSL 2 to the multicast address 239.255.0.1 and port 7650 UDP as this is what was being used by the pi to broadcast the talker messages.
So the wireshark shows that my windows desktop is recognizing the data being received from the talker node on the pi, but the WSL 2 does not receive this information. I think it might be a problem with how WSL 2 sets up its own private network.
I tried various configurations for ROS2. I set up initial peers and modified participant profiles in XML to set up static discovery. This did not work either (although it could be user error as I dont have much experience with XML).
Currently the WSL 2 is still unable to receive talker messages from pi. Again, the pi can successfully receive messages being sent by talker on WSL 2, just not the other way around.
Any help would be awesome! Thank you :D

This sounds like a network configuration issue in WSL. Have you checked that both machines are on the same subnet and hostnames/IPs for both machines are in each network config files? If you're using an older release of WSL it could also just be a limitation of WSL itself. Depending on what you're trying to do, ROS2 has Windows releases, which could be preferable for your setup.
